# most reliable mouse click check

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I properly check on Windows if some user has clicked some button? At the moment I have following click-check code:

```
bool cButton::isCursorCrossing ( ) const
{
    int posx, posy;
    g_pVGuiSurface->SurfaceGetCursorPos ( posx, posy );
    if ( posx > m_render_x && posx < m_render_x + buttonSize )
    {
        if ( posy > m_render_y && posy < m_render_y + buttonSize )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool cButton::isClicked ( ) const
{
    if ( isCursorCrossing ( ) )
    {
        if ( GetAsyncKeyState ( 0x01 ) & 1 )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it sometimes does not work - I have to click button 5 to 10 times to see result, I think this is caused by `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: That's not how buttons work in Windows. When the user clicks on a button, the system queues messages to indicate that the event has happened. I've no idea why you would be using `GetAsyncKeyState`. You'll want to throw all of this code away and go back to the drawing board. Step 1 is to learn about messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but I'm not using windows forms app - its using dx drawing system, and I'm creating plugin for it - so I don't receive messages

Comment: The question is tagged winapi. Perhaps you need to take a step back. Edit the question and provide clear details about what you are actually doing and give context for this code.

Comment: Most reliable would be to "subclass" whatever RAD component you have there and look for WM_LBUTTONCLICK. But indeed you need to know about Windows' message queue etc in order to do that. Also, please post which RAD tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to a event-like system, instead of polling. `GetAsyncKeyState` will tell you if the mouse button is down at the very moment you call it. It has no memory to report if the user has recently clicked. So it's natural that it won't work reliably. Your app is not responding to user actions, it's only by coincidence when it happens to line up.

Windows sends messages to your application so you can reliably handle events. In the case of a mouse button click, your window will receive `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

Either find a way to handle these messages yourself, or figure out how your framework can forward you these events.

Answer (score 0):

Well the most reliable is to use messages. The OS sends messages when an event eg. A mouse click occurs or a button on the keyboard is pressed/released.

So if you look into "Windows message loop" you will probably fond the answer. Night me allt to take in at first but it's every good knowledge for Windows programming.